# not getting any address id from Quickbooks Online when I query customers

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

When I query for customers I get back a customer object with all the info.  one of the properties is the Address.  this contains the billing and shipping addresses for the customer.  however, the id field for each address is always null.  I am wondering how I push an update back to QBO without the id?  how does QBO know which address I am changing without a key of some kind?  my goal is to be able to query QBO and get all the customers and address that have changed since a specified date.  I have all this working for the customer but need to do the same for addresses.  I am going by the assumption that when an address is changed in QBO that is sets the modified timestamp for that customer record. can anyone tell me how I manage the addresses for a customer and be able to push updates back to QBO?

Answer (score 1):

Try using tag(Billing/Shipping) attribute while updating the address. I've tested the same and it is working fine.

You mentioned earlier that you were getting the id field of address as null. It is becuase, the devkit works with both - QBO and QBD. QBD returns valid element id but QBO doesn't. So for QBO, Devkit shows null in place of element id(in your case - address's id).

You can test all these using api explorer(http://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer).
Hope it will solve your porb.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

'the id field for each address is always null' - this line is not very clear to me. Did you mean the id of the customer entity ? Plz explain.
  You can check the QBO-Customer object's documentation and sample update request xml, from the following Link - https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Customer .
   For testing you can use the api-explorer. Link - developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer

Thanks
Manas

Comment: I am talking about the id field on the individual address records under the customer record.

The Address property of the customer object is an array of "PhysicalAddress" objects.  If you look at each address object under the customer they also have an ‘id’ field.  This value is null for all the address for all the customers.  I am wondering how can I push an update for an address back to QB if I have no unique id for them

Comment: Here is some additional info so maybe its a little more clear.  This is the results in the debug window when I show the values of the address object...  notice the id field is null..

Comment: ? customers(0).Address(0)
{Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.PhysicalAddress}
    City: "Princeton"
    Country: Nothing
    CountryCode: Nothing
    CountrySubDivisionCode: "CA"
    County: Nothing
    CountyCode: Nothing
    DateLastVerified: #12:00:00 AM#
    DateLastVerifiedSpecified: False
    Default: False
    DefaultSpecified: False
    GeoCode: Nothing
    Id: Nothing
    IdsType: "Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo"
    Line1: "8032 County Road 61"
    Line2: Nothing
    Line3: Nothing
    Line4: Nothing
    Line5: Nothing
    PostalCode: "95970"
    PostalCodeSuffix: Nothing
    Tag: {Length=1}

Comment: Wow, All the carrage returns were stripped out. how lame is that